# CoreMedia Page error: this page is not part of the navigation

Tags: core-media

I have created a new page in CoreMedia 11 Studio. This page was supposed to be called from another page (the link to the new page was dislayed on the "parent" page).
The problem is that whenever I open the link it shows 404, and in the CoreMedia studio this error is displayed: "This page is not part of the navigation"

[image]

I already have a URL segment set in the metadata of the page. The page is also located in the same directory as the "parent" page.

Any ideas on how to fix the use would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the CoreMedia [fundamentals Video Cours](https://enablement.coremedia.com/course/coremedia-content-cloud-foundation-cms)e.

You have to add the child page to the Navigation list of the patent page.

1. Go to the parent page
2. open the navigation tab
3. Add the child page to the navigation list (by entering the name in the search field or dragging and dripping)

My mistake was that I was trying to add the parent page to the navigation list of the child.